# Set PATH variable for Flask WSGI app on Apache

Tags: python, apache

I have a simple Flask web app that is successfully running on Apache using `mod_wsgi`. However, the app itself imports [pypandoc](https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc), which is a thin wrapper for the [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) binary.

When I attempt to use the pandoc functionality within the app itself, I get an error that suggests `pypandoc` can't find an installation of pandoc.

Presumably this is because the pandoc binary is not within the system path of the special "apache" user that runs the server, but I can't figure out where and how to make the app aware of the pandoc binary.

I have tried to do a `sys.path.insert` within the WSGI script, and also tried to export the path to `/usr/local/bin` (or wherever I have pandoc) within the `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` file. But to no avail, either because my syntax was wrong or because (as I instead suspect) these aren't the proper solutions.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Apache supports a file named `envvars` where you can set the $PATH. It could be at `/etc/apache2/envvars` but it depends on your OS.

Comment: On my system I believe that is `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`, but I've tried exporting PATH there.

Answer (score 1):

Later discovered that the problem was unrelated to PATH. I was able to figure out the PATH used by the Apache user, but even after I moved pandoc to one of these path directories, I was still having trouble. After further debugging I realized that this pandoc binary was still trying to access data files from within my home folder, and Apache didn't have access to my home folder. So the question was really more specific to pandoc.